# Jade rendering engine for Laravel5?

Tags: laravel-5, pug

Is there actually a Jade template engine for Laravel5?
Jade code would be much easier to develop with, and - it would produce a compact HTML code.

Comment: You can use build tools to compile Jade to HTML. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade

Answer (score 6):

I am new to Laravel since today, figuring out the same question you have.
I think there are two different approches:

## Compiling via build tools

First you could use npm, gulp and elixir - witch both come with Laravel.
Therefore you have to have npm and gulp installed (I assume you already have).
 Use the `laravel-elixir-jade` module via

```
npm i --save-dev laravel-elixir-jade
```

After adding a couple of lines in your gulpfile you can run the default task via

```
gulp
```

Here is an example of an elixir function inside the `gulpfile.js`

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-jade');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less')
       .jade({
        baseDir: './resources',
        blade: true,
        dest: '/views/',
        pretty: true,
        search: '**/*.jade',
        src: '/jade/'
    });
});
```

Dont forget the `require('laravel-elixir-jade');` at the beginning.

## Compiling at server-side

You also have the possibility to let the PHP-Server render your jade files while rendering the page. I have created a package called `mhochm/laravel-jadephp` could be the right module for you.

I promise:

> Create views as always but in Jade syntax

Require this package with composer:

```
composer require mhochm/laravel-jadephp
```

Add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in config/app.php:

```
'mhochm\LaravelJadePHP\LaravelJadePHPServiceProvider',
```

I hope this will help you :)

Moses

Comment: thank you very much, I've been using laravel-elixir-jade for a while, but it always compiles all .jade files into .blade.php, so I wrote my own jade2blade script, which works without gulp, it watches for file changes on the .jade files and only compiles the necessary files. [https://github.com/eschmid72/jade2blade/](https://github.com/eschmid72/jade2blade/)